# iPhone, how to send a data change event to the UIView from the application delegator?

Tags: iphone, events, ios

I setup a network call in appdelegator class to get some infomation back, and I want to show it in the frist UIView. How to pass the data to that UIView?

I mean the UIView may be visible or may be destroyed and replaced by other one, if it was visible, how to pass that value to it?

is there any publish/subscribe events mechanism in iphone sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few different ways, including using [key-value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) or [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s.

The basic idea is that when you load your `UIView`, you want to register it as an observer of a key path/posted notification of the app delegate. When you deallocate your view, you should unregister it as an observer.